# Error converting data in MFL

Tags: xml, mainframe, osb, ebcdic, copybook

I have a MFL in OSB that converts data received from mainframe system to XML . Till recently it was working fine . But recently mainframe system started sending some data which in OSB is seen like this âäàáãåçñ¢éêëèíîïìßÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑøÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØæÆý£¥©Ý®ôöòóõûüùúÿÔÖÒÓÕÛÜÙÚ. Seems its the ebcidic data which is not in the ascii character set .

MFL fails to transform this data . Please advise what is going on here and any workaround . I tried all options in MFL configuration like treating this field as ebcidic , using different base code etc .

Error thrown by MFL :

```
ErrorMessage : Error decoding data.
 Detail 
  Name: ExpectedValue
  Value : UTF-8
```

Comment: Well, it looks like recently someone changed something on the Mainframe and broke the process. You should raise it with the Mainframe Support team. You shouldn't need to go changing stuff yourself without some new or changed specification. You'll get undone again if/when someone fixes the Mainframe side. You need the transfer/conversion of data back as it was before, or you need a spec with all the approvals.